# git show <commit> --oneline not showing oneline

Tags: git, msysgit

I am using version 1.8.3 of mysysgit and it seems that the --oneline command does not give me just one line per commit, I get all of the diff lines as well.

```
git show HEAD --oneline
```

and even `git show HEAD --pretty="%h %s"`

do not give just one line.

(note: same results using both git bash and posh git)

The reason I want the show --oneline is I want to pipe the results of a rev-list query into it from posh git.

```
git rev-list <somestuff> | %{git show $_ --oneline}
```

Comment: add `--no-patch`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think this'll do what you want
`git show --no-patch --oneline`

Comment: haha - this is a very old question - but yes you are right :-)

Comment: `--no-patch`! that's the flag I was looking for, thanks

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Only for complementing the @Justin answer, the `--oneline` is working, but the **diff** output (think it as `git diff`) is still getting printed. So you see the commit meta data in one single line but the block of changes is printed below it. Then comes the `--no-patch` option which supress the diff output, accordingly to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt---no-patch)

Answer (score 16):

May

```
git log HEAD --oneline --no-walk
```

is what you want.

BTW, there is `--pretty` and `--oneline` the same as `git log` in `git rev-list`, maybe the pipe is unnecessary.

Comment: the answer does not however explains why `git show HEAD --oneline` does not produce an output as stated in the documentation: `<sha1> <title line> This is designed to be as compact as possible.`

Comment: But why isn't it an one-liner :P ?